# Is there a reason MySQL code will work on local machine but fails on Heroku? ( _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError)

Tags: python, flask, heroku, jinja2

My code, which deploys from github directly to Heroku. When I test the site on my local machine it runs without error. All the versions of mysql are the same on my machine as Heroku. I can't see why there would be any issues

## Jinja

```
get_user_notis(session\['username'\])
```

## SQL

```
mycursor.execute("""
                SELECT * FROM notif WHERE username = %s ORDER BY date DESC
                """, (username, ))
```

## error (main error code at the very bottom)

File "/app/flask_app.py", line 478, in index

```
2024-01-16T04:35:47.769366+00:00 app[web.1]:     return render_template("index.html")

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769366+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769367+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 151, in render_template

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769367+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _render(app, template, context)

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769367+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769367+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 132, in _render

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769367+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = template.render(context)

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769367+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769367+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1301, in render

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769367+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.environment.handle_exception()

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769368+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769369+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769369+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/templates/index.html", line 31, in top-level template code

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769370+00:00 app[web.1]:     {{ navbar_block() }}

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769370+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 777, in _invoke

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769370+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self._func(*arguments)

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769370+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769370+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/templates/macros.html", line 583, in template

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769370+00:00 app[web.1]:     {% for item in get_user_notis(session['username']) %}

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769371+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769371+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/helpers/notif.py", line 13, in get_user_notis

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769371+00:00 app[web.1]:     mycursor.execute("""

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769371+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 317, in execute

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769371+00:00 app[web.1]:     prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769371+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769373+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 780, in prepare_for_mysql

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769373+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769373+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-01-16T04:35:47.769373+00:00 app[web.1]: _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type Undefined cannot be converted
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us the full error message.

Comment: @JohnGordon im sorry im not sure how i forgot that

Comment: Based on the error, the query does not even get to mysql. The issue seems to be with the parameter being undefined.

Comment: You need to provide more code, please share the portion where you attempt to make the connection to the db. Wild guess, maybe on your local machine you don't need to pass a password but in Heroku you might.

Comment: Did you [Add ClearDB to application](https://autoidle.com/blog/how-to-create-a-mysql-application-on-heroku#:~:text=Adding%20ClearDB%20to%20application)?

Comment: @vgenovpy i mean sure. i have 12 areas where SQL works so thats why its confusing. its all using copy and pasted code lol